# Why I cannot run npm run dev on a centos7?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I have a problem installing my app on a new server, I come from `centos6` to `centos7`.

When I am installing a `Laravel` app that works perfectly on `centos6` it goes right except when I run `npm run dev`

```
[root@v6-a10 worknow4.0]# npm run dev

> dev
> npm run development


> development
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

node:events:306
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js EACCES
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:275:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21) {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'spawn node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js',
  path: 'node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js',
  spawnargs: [
    '--progress',
    '--hide-modules',
    '--config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/admin/domains/worknow-cursos.com/public_html/worknow4.0
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-02-07T19_56_43_919Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/admin/domains/worknow-cursos.com/public_html/worknow4.0
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c npm run development

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-02-07T19_56_44_006Z-debug.log
```

I have been searching for an answer for hours but nothing works.

**I tried to delete node_modules and package-lock and reinstall**, but also didn't work.

Comment: `EACCES` means permissions issue

Comment: See if the log tells you what file needs different permissions when it tries to open it.

Comment: l change node_modules access with **chown -Rf admin:admin worknow4.0**, from root root. Now when i run npm run dev y get  npm run dev

> dev
> npm run development

sh: npm: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem might be permission as dimitri says. I just go to node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js and change the permission to 777

I dont know if this is recomended but at least works

Comment: `777` is never recomendet...